# Как определить, что класс реализует данный интерфейс?

Tags: typescript

```
interface A{ }

class B implements A{ }

let m: any = new B();
```

Нужно проверить, что m реализует интерфейс А и выполнить некое действие.

Comment: думаю что это сделать нельзя, так как иинтерфейсы не компилируються в джс. Можно разве что написать `let m: A = new B()`, тогда мы получим экземпляр класса приведенный к интерфейсу.

Comment: Это плохо если честно, а я тут расшагался широкими шагами как в C#. Придётся мудрить.

Comment: можете вместо интерфейса абстрактный класс взять. Тогда через `instanceof` можно проверить

Answer (score 0):

Самой проверки как таковой скорее всего нет. Но вот если вы укажете свойство в `A`:

```
interface A {
    name: string; 
}
```

Затем выполните такой код:

```
class B implements A{ }
```

То компилятор выдаст вам ошибку так как в `B` вы должны будете обявить `name`.

Так же советую воспользоваться наследованием `extends`.  И обратиться к конструктору наследуемого класса через `super`.

Answer (score 0):

В TypeScript применяется "утиная типизация", поэтому "m реализует интерфейс А" означает "m обладает свойствами, описанными в A".

Такую проверку можно реализовать с помощью [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

```
interface A{
  z: any;
  y: () => {};
}

function isA(x: any): x is A {
  return 'z' in A;
}

let m: any = new B();

if (isA(m)) {
  m.y(); // компилятор знает, что m реализует A
}
```